# Python datascience.tables.Table.plot does not show the graph

Tags: python

Don't know why the graph is not showing up.  There is no error message at all. I have tried both in command line and jupyter in Visual Source Code. Nothing is showing up.

```
import datascience as ds

table = ds.Table().with_columns(
    'days',  ds.make_array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'price', ds.make_array(90.5, 90.00, 83.00, 95.50, 82.00, 82.00),
    'projection', ds.make_array(90.75, 82.00, 82.50, 82.50, 83.00, 82.50))

table.plot('days')
```

Do I miss anything? Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package. However, I can imagine that those who are familiar will need more information. Are you running this on the command line? In spyder or jupyter notebooks or somewhere else?

Comment: I have tried both in jupyter in visual source code and direct from command line.  Not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, in jupyter I have to add the following at the top to make the inline graph shows up.

**%matplotlib inline.**

Below is the complete code. Please noted the code on the 2nd line.

```
import datascience as ds
%matplotlib inline

table = ds.Table().with_columns(
    'days',  ds.make_array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'price', ds.make_array(90.5, 90.00, 83.00, 95.50, 82.00, 82.00),
    'projection', ds.make_array(90.75, 82.00, 82.50, 82.50, 83.00, 82.50))

table.plot('days')
```